# Linking to Paid Version

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have two targets of my app: 1 is the free version with ads and the other is the paid version that removes ads. I have a link in my free version that takes the user to the app store to the paid version link.

My question is, if I use this setup will the users highscore from the free version be kept if they choose to buy the paid version? I don't want the users data to be reset. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You avoid this problem by having 1 app - the free version with ads which also has an in-app purchase to remove the ads.

Comment: Okay thank you! So I would just have one target then correct?

Comment: Yes, no need for the paid app.

Comment: Yes, I also recommend one app, however, if you really want to stick to two apps (or maybe at some point you want to have two apps with the same leaderboards) you can set up your game in dev center as part of a group and then you can share highscores to the same leaderbord from multiple apps. (ALSO BE WARNED that apps part of a group in game center cannot be deleted)